# why the UITableView isn't showed anything?nothing display data.. Crazy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

why the UITableView isn't showed anything?nothing display data.

[image]

pure code,do not using SB

Comment: did you check your tableview delegate called or not?

Comment: have you set your tableview datasource and delegate to your viewcontroller

Comment: add in your .h file<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
or [self.tableview setDelegate:self];

Comment: we need somemore code please update your class code

Comment: TableView delegates are not set 
Set <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> delegates

Comment: The more code has added..please enter image description

Comment: Please, stop inserting code as pictures, it's dreadful. Use the code block instead (may the Markdown be with you).

Comment: Thank you, I am a novice

Comment: thank you for each answer sincerely..My project another SJTabBarViewController this class creates a view covers the tableView..So stupid mistake..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

see that the class you implemented the tableview and the storyboard view controller have the same class name

Answer (score -2):

You need to check following things:

1> did your tableview outlet connected?

2> did datasource/delegate connected?

3> put breakpoint on cellforrow and number of rows to conform your delegate and datasource connection.

4> check cell if you are using same identifier "Cell".

Answer (score -2):

I think you added tableview as a subview. And if delegate methods are not called then after adding it into your view reload it. May be it will work.

```
[tableview reloaddata];
```